Cordova zip32 cannot place CD entry
I cannot build my cordova app as it says:

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
Zip32 cannot place CD entry 'assets/www/assets/pdfs/section1/product3/tn.png' payload at 4469793404 (MAX=4294967295)

but the file tn.png is only 0.5 MB. The whole /www folder counts to 7.4 GB with 3829 files.
I followed the offical documentation and tested it with the basic app which worked and put out an apk.
How do I enable zip64?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
